# Solve $7^x \equiv 6 \pmod{17}$ given 3 is a primitive root $\bmod 17$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, primitive-roots

It's easy to show that 3 is a primitive root $\bmod 17$,
but how do I use it prove the congruence?

Is there a general way to solve any congruence of the form $a^x \equiv b \pmod{c}$ if you know a primitive root $\bmod c$ and c is big (without brute force)?

Comment: Well, a way is to try out all the $x$s in the range $[0,15]$:-). A more useful answer is that this is closely related to [the notorious discrete  logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). There are more efficient methods than brute force. For example you can utilize the factorization of $\phi(c)$. Note, because your base is not necessarily a primitive root, it is possible that there are no solutions.

Comment: so there is no general solution to for bigger c without using brute force ?

Comment: Boris, depends on what you call brute force. There are methods significantly faster than testing each and every $x$. That Wikipedia page links to seven types of attacks. But none have a polynomial complexity. This is the reason some cryptographic methods based on the difficulty of the discrete logarithm problem (such as Diffie-Hellman) are considered safe.

Comment: See [this earlier answer by yours truly](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/561569/11619) for an example of what using one of the approaches entails. Notice that the example there is not "general". In a homework assignment something lucky must happen for the task to be reasonable :-)

Comment: sorry for ambiguity what i mean is there a way to solve it by hand within reasonable time (30mins) for c > 500 for example . i guess no since polynomial complexity is easy for computer but not for me :D . thanks for explaining ..... i saw this problem in a problem set and thought there is some fast and elegant way to solve it , using euler totient function or some other neat method . but now it makes perfect sense since the next topic in the course was RSA .

Comment: Correct. No fast way to do this by hand. I'm not sure I would want to do it by hand for a measly 3-digit $c$ unless I designed the example specifically so that one of the methods works well.

Comment: I don't see why it helps to know that $3$ is a primitive root. See my comment to abspht's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here if you observe that $7=3^{11}\quad \& \quad 6=3^{15}$ so Putting above we have

$3^{11x}\equiv 3^{15}~ \pmod{17}$

$\implies 3^{11x-15}\equiv 1 \pmod{17}$

3 is primitive root so  $11x-15=16n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

$\implies x=\dfrac{16n+15}{11}$ will be integer

You can easily see that $n=8$ satifies this ,So $x=13$ will be a solution of given .

There will be more solution of this too.

Comment: thanks but is there a general way to solve it without using brute force? if c was a bigger number instead of 17 this brute force solution would take very long time .

Comment: $7^3 = 3$ is pretty easy to see, and substituting that into the $6=3^{15}$ will get you there quite fast. It still boils down to brute force and lucky guesses, of course.

Comment: If we're allowed to "observe" that $7=3^{11}$ and $6=3^{15}$, why can't we just "observe" directly that $7^{13}=6$? I'm not faulting your answer $-$ I think it's a bad question.

Comment: TonyK its two step problem . i omitted the first step . so yes your right . first step is proving that 3 is primitive root mod 17 . so at the process you compute $3^{11} \mod 17$ and $3^{15} \mod 17$ and use your previous computations .(you dont need to compute $7^{13}$ so you cant "observe" it)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of brute force quite significantly. Using an interval $d$ of approximately $\sqrt{c}$, make an "island" of values $a\cdot g^i$ with $i\in \{0,d{-}1\}$, then calculate all $g^{jd}$ and identify the coinciding value.

$\begin{array}{c|c}
k\ (d=4) &g^k & a\cdot g^k & b\cdot g^k \\ \hline
0  & 1 & 7 & 6 \\
1  & 3 & \color{red}{4} & \color{violet}{1} \\
2  & 9 & 12 & 3 \\
3  & 10 & 2 & 9 \\
4  & 13\\
8  & 16\\
12  & \color{red}{4}\\
16  & \color{violet}{1}\\
\end{array}$

giving, $\bmod 17$, $7\cdot 3\equiv 3^{12}$ and $6\cdot 3\equiv 3^{16}$ , so $7\equiv 3^{11}$ and  $6\equiv 3^{15}$.

Then we need to find $11x\equiv 15 \bmod 16 (=\phi(17))$, which means finding the inverse of $11\bmod 16$, which here is $3$, giving $x\equiv 15\cdot 3 \equiv 13\bmod 16$.

Obviously for this exercise in small numbers this is more work thn simply calculating the powers of $7 \bmod 17$, but for larger numbers it avoids calculating all powers.

Because $3$ is a primitive root $\bmod 17$, we are guaranteed to find suitable exponents in the first stage.